# Getting list values from window in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, types, casting

I wonder if is it possible to get values from tkinter entry as list (including types).

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
base = '1,None,1'
items = StringVar(window, value=base)

def submit():
    result = list(items.get().split(','))
    print(result)

Entry(window, bg='white', textvariable=items).place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, anchor='nw') 
Button(window, text='Submit', command=submit).place(relx=0.9, rely=0.9, anchor='se')

window.mainloop()
```

This will give output `['1', 'None', '1']` and what I need is `[1, None, 1]`. If solution needs to iterate through list and check each element how can change string `'None'` to `NoneType`?

Comment: You will have to use methods like `isinstance()`

Comment: This has more to do with [typecasting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp) than `tkinter` itself.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: your suggestion doesn't make sense. They are explicitly setting the entry to a string with the word `None`. `isinstance` will return that it's a string.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was saying methods like `isinstance()` to ID what the instance is. Or something like `isdecimal()`, `isdigit()` and so on. They are also wanting to convert each list item to the equivalent Type.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: `isinstance` is not at all the same as `isdecimal` and `isdigit`. The last two are string methods, `isinstance` looks at the actual type of an object.

Comment: @BryanOakley ah ok. I was a little confused on that method then. I thought it was a string method that checked if that string match with any object type listed in the following tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to tkinter that will return the contents of an entry widget in anything other than string form. However, you can certainly get the value and parse it according to whatever rules you want (split on spaces or commas, for example).

In your specific example, since you're explicitly setting a value to a string that includes the word `None`, you can check for that specific string and do the conversion. For example:

```
def submit():
    result = [None if x.strip() == 'None' else x for x in items.get().split(',')]
    print(result)
```

Comment: where does it convert '1' to 1?

Comment: Do I need to use `x.strip()`? `x == 'None'` gives me the same result. After `else` I just put `int(x)` and it works for me.

Comment: @Ethr: I added the call to `strip` to handle someone typing it in like `1, None, 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use various methods to check what a string is equal to.

Here is a simple example to get the results you are looking for.
Keep in mind it may need work for other values you are needing but you can add on to it.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
base = '1,None,1'
items = StringVar(window, value=base)

def submit():
    x = items.get().split(',')
    results = []
    for item in x:
        if item.isdigit():
            results.append(int(item))
        elif item in ('None', 'none', None):
            results.append(None)
        else:
            results.append(item)

    print(results)

Entry(window, bg='white', textvariable=items).place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, anchor='nw') 
Button(window, text='Submit', command=submit).place(relx=0.9, rely=0.9, anchor='se')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The result of `.split(` is already a `list`, no need to use `list(...)`.

Comment: @stovfl true. Most of the code was just copy paste from the OP. Corrected.